# RecyclerView filterable performFiltering() not working after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-filterable

After I migrating to AndroidX, I just noticed that my search functionality not working anymore. I've checked on official docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable but no clue.

This is my RecyclerView adapter `ListProdukAdapter.kt` that implements Filterable:

```
class ListProdukAdapter(private val context: Context, private val data: List<Produk>, private val act: MainActivity, private val kategori: String) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListProdukAdapter.SampleViewHolders>(), Filterable {
    private var dataFiltered: List<Produk>? = null
    private val h: Helper
    private val a: HelperAplikasi

    init {
        this.dataFiltered = data
        this.h = act.h
        this.a = act.a
    }

    ...

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): Filter.FilterResults {
                val keyword = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()
                dataFiltered = if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
                    data
                } else {
                    val filteredList = ArrayList<Produk>()
                    var kategoriBf = ""
                    var kategoriHit = 0
                    val kategoriNum = HashMap<String, Int>()
                    for (res in data) {
                        if (!h.cekVal(res.judul) || h.cekFilter(keyword, res.judul, res.kategorI_LENGKAP, res.keywords) > 0) {
                            filteredList.add(res)
                            if (h.cekVal(res.judul)) {
                                if (kategoriBf != res.kategori && !kategoriBf.isEmpty()) {
                                    kategoriNum[kategoriBf] = kategoriHit
                                    kategoriHit = 0
                                }
                                kategoriHit++
                                kategoriBf = res.kategori
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    kategoriNum[kategoriBf] = kategoriHit
                    Log.e("kategori_num", kategoriNum.toString())
                    Log.e("kategori_num_item_bf", filteredList.size.toString() + "")
                    for (etl in filteredList) {
                        if (!h.cekVal(etl.judul)) {
                            val jumlah = kategoriNum[etl.kategori]
                            if (jumlah == null || jumlah < 1)
                                etl.stok = 0
                            else
                                etl.stok = jumlah
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("kategori_num_item_af", filteredList.size.toString() + "")
                    filteredList
                }
                val filterResults = Filter.FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = dataFiltered ?: ArrayList<Produk>()
                return filterResults
            }

            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: Filter.FilterResults) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                dataFiltered = filterResults.values as ArrayList<Produk>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Note that it works like a charm before I migrating to AndroidX. My `h.cekFilter()` method is just my custom helper for String checking whether it's containing the keyword or not, no problem there. Now I got this crash whenever I type anything in my search input:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.ArrayList<com.jukat.jualdekat.objects.Produk> /* = java.util.ArrayList<com.jukat.jualdekat.objects.Produk> */
        at com.jukat.jualdekat.adapters.ListProdukAdapter$getFilter$1.publishResults(ListProdukAdapter.kt:239)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

When I try changing (line number 239) from `dataFiltered = filterResults.values as ArrayList<Produk>` to `dataFiltered = filterResults.values as ArrayList<Produk>?`, result is zero even when I type 1 letter that obviously contained on the data. Yeah, I got this same error in my all other activities which using similar implementation. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you migrate manually by changing dependencies or via IntelliJ?

Comment: @nimi0112 via Refactor menu in Android Studio 3.2

Comment: @pskink I didn't know about that. Could you give me an example or reference?

Comment: @pskink no way :/ that's seems like an outdated and bloated custom class of adapter. It using inner class `ArrayFilter()` extends from `Filter` which is like my `getFilter()` which is not working anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184854/discussion-between-taufik-nur-rahmanda-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys. I took few hours figuring out this problem and eventually I found what actually it is. Apparently this problem is not related to AndroidX at all, instead because of my custom method that is in my `Helper` class which I happened to convert it from Java to Kotlin right before I migrated to AndroidX which then made me mistaken it.

The `performFiltering()` method have a nullable `CharSequence` parameter, so I should have `CharSequence?` in my `h.cekFilter()` method like bellow.

```
fun cekFilter(keyword: CharSequence?, vararg teks: CharSequence?): Int {
    ...
}
```

Another problem is Logcat not showing any sign of error in my `Helper` class, instead my `performFilter()` stopped halfway and then passing null `filterResults.values` to `publishResults()` which is then triggered exception in Logcat. Weird.